# I have a problem locating the input tag that is inside the div tag

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I need send text to the input tag, but return error: "Unable to locate element".

The element input is inside the div tag and do not is posible locate it.

I use xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabla_filter\"]/label/input")).sendKeys("text to send");
```

How can select the element?

```
<div class="col-xa-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div id="table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>
            "Buscar:"
            <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder aria-controls="tabla"> == $0
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider giving us more context. Your question is tagged with Selenium, but using stating that this question is regarding Selenium will help people better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath

```
//*[@id='tabla_filter']/label/input
```